# How to extract numbers from Excel formula that are not part of string constant

Tags: javascript, excel, parsing, numbers, formula

I have a complex Excel formula in JavaScript string variable:

```
=IF(F5=1;"";
IF(F8=1;"Процентная ставка до постройки";
IF(F8=2.7;CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в 1-ый год";G21);
IF(F8=3;CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в первые 3 года";G21);
CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в первые 5 лет";G21)))))
```

I need to extract "pure" numbers from this and replace them with ones multiplied by 10^10.
So the string should turn into

```
=IF(F5=10000000000;"";
IF(F8=10000000000;"Процентная ставка до постройки";
IF(F8=27000000000;CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в 1-ый год";G21);
IF(F8=30000000000;CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в первые 3 года";G21);
CONCATENATE("Процентная ставка в первые 5 лет";G21)))))
```

I do not want to touch numbers, that are inside string consts (1-ый, 5 лет) or cell names (F5, G21).

Is there any easy way to do this, any regular expression or something?

I really don't want any brainf*cking parsing...

Comment: Are all the numbers you want to replace prefixed with `=`?

Comment: No. There may be any symbol allowed in excel formula. Opening parenthesis, any number of spaces, some math symbol(+,-,*,/,^), I wonder what else.

Comment: Any example for those specific cases? Also, would be good if you could add what you have tried so far. You mentioned regular expressions, I deduce you should have some notion of how to use it.

Comment: Some of examples I have: `=VLOOKUP(D7;'Валюта кредита'!B5:E7;4;0)`  `=C42*C33/(1-C33)`   `=IF(AND(G9=C31;F5=1);C45;IF(F5=1;IF(F8=1;C49/12;C48/12);IF(F8=1;C47/12;C47/12)))` Regular expression /[^a-zA-Z][\d\.]+/ extracts numbers, but it doesn't consider any quotes.

Comment: Huh, you have vlookups too? You intend to get `=VLOOKUP(D7;'Валюта кредита'!B5:E7;40000000000;0)` as output for this line?

Comment: Oh, sh**... Of course, not. Now I see, it's nearly impossible. I should review my initial task (actually, I'm fighting floating-point calculation) and find some other way. Thanks for pointing to this issue!

Comment: Hmm, try to see if this works as you intended maybe? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kLR2N/2/) Replace the initial string with the different formulas and click on `Run` to execute it again. Disclaimer though, I'm not all that familiar with JS!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to declare a variable that has quotes and double quotes without manually escaping them... ^^; (the vlookup formula uses single quotes)